# Floating Ribbon and page height

Tags: branding

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.greggalipeau.com/2011/01/28/a-better-enhanced-sharepoint-2010-floating-ribbon/) for removing sharepoint's ribbon positioning system and letting the ribbon float at the top.  It works great, but the height of my outer divs for my custom branding are getting set to the height of the visible window, which destroys the design.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought of the answer as I was typing the question, but I went ahead and entered the question and am going to document my solution below.

I had the divs relating to my design OUTSIDE the `s4-workspace` and `s4-bodyContainer` divs.  I moved them INSIDE these two divs and my divs aren't getting their height set by SharePoint's javascript anymore.